# Connecting to TorBrowser Socket

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, socks

I'm trying to connect to tor from my `c++` application using [this tutorial](https://yaseeneltii.me/connecting-to-tor-from-c-socks5/), but I want to connect to the tor session that is run by Tor Browser. At the moment I cannot get past the `Resp1` thing, since I'm getting `Resp1[1] == 0x20`.

How can I connect to the existing tor session managed by Tor Browser? Is this tutorial valid, or not any more?

Comment: Could you paste the source code into your question? This helps to see what you did and we can give you an answer.

Comment: @JensKubieziel at the moment I have the very same code as in the tutorial (just without that Linux&Mac stuff, since I'm on Win7)

Comment: @JensKubieziel And I've also tried using port 9150, but with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the tutorial linked in the question does not work correctly with TorBrowser, but I managed to connect to TorBrowser socket on port 9150 and use it in my app by rewriting the app in Qt (which I was going to do sooner or later) and simply using the `QNetworkProxy` class:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::Socks5Proxy);
proxy.setHostName("localhost");
proxy.setPort(9150);
QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

This answer will not help everyone, but it's kind of a workaround and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the stand-alone tor application (referenced in the tutorial you mention) instead of the Tor Browser Bundle. TBB appears to not open a port on 9050 as tor by itself would.

Documentation of TBB seems conflicting on what port can be used. https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#TBBSocksPort mentions SOCKS on port 9150, though older documentation mentions an option called 'Configure ControlPort automatically' that appears to randomise the ports used by TBB.